# Updating dataset in recyclerview while scrolling sends the scroll to the top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, notifydatasetchanged

Needless to say, I came across a lot of proposed solutions for this particular problem. I removed scrollListener and implemented it inside my fragment, I used notifyItemRangeInserted instead of notifyDataSetChanged. The thing is, none of those solutions did work for me...I'm displaying a set of youtube videos in my app. My dataset is indeed updated; thing is when I scroll downwards, at some point the scroll position moves to the top i.e the very first item of my dataset  Here's a snippet of my activity :

```
private void setUpRecyclerView()
{
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))
            {
                loadMorePosts();
                loading = true;
            }
        }
    });

    initAdapter();
}

private void initAdapter()
{
    adapter = new MyAdapter(mDataSet, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    skeletonScreen = Skeleton.bind(mRecyclerView)
            .adapter(adapter)
            .shimmer(true)
            .angle(30)
            .duration(1200)
            .count(10)
            .load(R.layout.youtube_item)
            .show();
}

private void loadVideos(final OnLoadPlayListCallback videosCallback, String pageToken)
{
    Call<FullChannelPlayListData> mcallPlayList = mYouTubeService.getPlayList(
            Tags.VALUE_SNIPPET,
            20,
            mPlayListId,
            getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.youtube_data_api_key),
            pageToken
            );

    mcallPlayList.enqueue(new Callback<FullChannelPlayListData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FullChannelPlayListData> call, Response<FullChannelPlayListData> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200)
            {
                Log.d("FullPlayListSuccessful", response.message());
                videosCallback.onSuccessfulRequest(response.body());
            }
            else Log.d("FullPlayListUnsuccess", response.message());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FullChannelPlayListData> call, Throwable t) {
            videosCallback.onFailureRequest(t);
        }
    });
}

 @Override
public void onSuccessfulRequest(FullChannelPlayListData fullChannelPlayListData)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccessfulRequest Item size = "+ fullChannelPlayListData.getItems().size());
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mNextPageToken))
        removeFooter();

    for (FullPlayListItems mItem: fullChannelPlayListData.getItems())
    {
        FullPlayListItems randomItem = getVideoFromDataSet(mItem.getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId(), mDataSet);
        if (randomItem == null) {
            mDataSet.add(mItem);
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(adapter.getItemCount(), mDataSet.size());

    mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            skeletonScreen.hide();
        }
    }, 2000);


    mNextPageToken = fullChannelPlayListData.getNextPageToken();
    setLoaded();

}

public void setLoaded() {
    loading = false;
}
```

I could use really use some help...

**UPDATE** MyAdapter class

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{

    private List<FullPlayListItems> mDataSet;
    private Context mActivity;
    private static final int YOUTUBE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int PROGRESS_BAR_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    public MyAdapter(List<FullPlayListItems> mDataSet, Context mActivity) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }


    public class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        @BindView(R.id.pBarLoadMorePosts)
        ProgressBar pBarLoadMore;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDataSet.get(position) != null ? YOUTUBE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE : PROGRESS_BAR_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (viewType == PROGRESS_BAR_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE)
        {
            View pBarLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.footer_loader, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ProgressViewHolder(pBarLayoutView);
        }
        else
        {
            View postItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.youtube_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new YoutubeItemViewHolder(postItemLayoutView);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        FullPlayListItems mVideoItem = mDataSet.get(position);

        switch (viewType)
        {
            case PROGRESS_BAR_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                ProgressViewHolder progressViewHolder = (ProgressViewHolder) holder;
                progressViewHolder.pBarLoadMore.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(CoreApplication.getRes().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                break;
            case YOUTUBE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
            default:
                YoutubeItemViewHolder youtubeItemViewHolder = (YoutubeItemViewHolder) holder;
                youtubeItemViewHolder.mVideoTitle.setText(mVideoItem.getSnippet().getTitle());
                youtubeItemViewHolder.sdvYoutubeThumbnail.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mVideoItem.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getHigh().getUrl()));

        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet != null ? mDataSet.size() : 0;
    }

    public class YoutubeItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView mVideoTitle;
        SimpleDraweeView sdvYoutubeThumbnail;

        public YoutubeItemViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mVideoTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_title);
            sdvYoutubeThumbnail = (SimpleDraweeView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sdv_thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my onViewCreated:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mPlayListId = getArguments().getString(Tags.YT_CHANNEL_PLAYLIST_ID);
    setUpRecyclerView();
    // Like I said initially mNextPageToken is empty
    loadVideos(this, mNextPageToken);
}
```

Comment: How do you update your adapter dataset in loadMorePost()

Comment: It's just the network request using retrofit...In case everything is successful, I just provided the callback for the successful request..So since my adapter has already been initialised in onViewCreated, I just need to update the itemCount inside onSuccessfulRequest()

Comment: Could you please share that code for reference

Comment: It's the onSuccessfulRequest() which gets called....The first time, the parameter mNextPageToken is empty..So when I scroll downwards and load more mNextPageToken is no more empty....So the same onSuccessfulRequest() method is called... The variable mDataSet which holds the list is initially empty when it is bound to the adapter; so when I make the request for the 1st time, the list is updated inside onSuccessfulRequest() as well as the getItemCount from the adapter

Comment: try to add adapter.notifyItemInserted(mDataset.size()-1)  below mDataSet.add(mItem);   and  remove  adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(adapter.getItemCount(), mDataSet.size());   .Please let me know the result

Comment: Yeah....well I have the same thing....the dataset is updated but on scrolling down the scroll (suddenly) position moves to the top

Comment: That's strange. Please post your MyAdapter code also

Comment: I updated my question with the adapter

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just notify the data change in the onSuccessfulRequest() method.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This doesn't work either (This is the 1st thing I did initially)...That's why I decided to give a try to the other notify methods as per several post I read here on S.O from users who encountered the same problem

Comment: Nope...just updating it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this answer is helpful to you. anyway please try,

Add this method to your `MyAdapter`

```
public void addItem(VideoSectionsActivity item){
mDataSet.add(item);
notifyItemInserted(mDataSet.size() - 1);
}
```

And change your `onSuccessfulRequest()`

```
@Override
public void onSuccessfulRequest(FullChannelPlayListData fullChannelPlayListData)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccessfulRequest Item size = "+ fullChannelPlayListData.getItems().size());
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(mNextPageToken))
        removeFooter();

    for (FullPlayListItems mItem: fullChannelPlayListData.getItems())
    {
        FullPlayListItems randomItem = getVideoFromDataSet(mItem.getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId(), mDataSet);
        if (randomItem == null) {
            adapter.addItem(mItem);
        }
    }



    mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            skeletonScreen.hide();
        }
    }, 2000);


    mNextPageToken = fullChannelPlayListData.getNextPageToken();
    setLoaded();

}
```

**Updated**

And also rearrange your code in activity

```
    private void setUpRecyclerView()
{
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    initAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))
            {
                loadMorePosts();
                loading = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Same thing here mate.....the dataset is updated but still, upon scrolling down, the scroll position moves suddenly to the top (1st item) of my list